# The parameters to be passed in fetch API to get data from google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api, fetch-api

What url should i pass as a parameter of ferch() to connect to my google sheet. Simple google sheet API url is not working as there is no option in it to mention my spreadsheet id. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data from a Google Spreadsheet you have to call the `spreadsheet.values.get` API endpoint by performing a *GET* request to:

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/**YOU SPREADSHEET ID**/values/**THE RANGE OF DATA YOU WANT TO GET**

You can experiment with the API on [this link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get).